# Subquery in Linq to Entities throw Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, subquery

I have an issue and i have no idea about, my project has many queries using linq to entities and subqueries, these are working for other people, but when I try to run them in my pc all the queries return "Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context".

Look at this example:

```
 var  questoesRetorno = (from q in questoes
         join p in ctx.tblConcurso_Provas on q.intProvaID equals p.intProvaID
         join c in ctx.tblConcursoes on p.ID_CONCURSO equals c.ID_CONCURSO
         join favorita1 in favoritos on q.intQuestaoID equals favorita1.IdQuestao into favorita2
         from favorita in favorita2.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new PPQuestao
         {
             Id = q.intQuestaoID,
             Ano = q.intYear.Value,
             Ordem = q.intOrder.Value,
             Prova = new Prova()
             {
                 ID = p.intProvaID
             },
             Concurso = new Concurso()
             {
                 Ano = c.VL_ANO_CONCURSO.Value,
                 Sigla = c.SG_CONCURSO.Trim(),
                 UF = c.CD_UF.Trim()
             },
             FavoritadaPor = favorita.Professor,
             EmClassificacaoPor = (from emClassificacao in ctx.tblConcursoQuestaoEmClassificacao
                                   join pessoa in ctx.tblPersons on emClassificacao.intEmployeeID equals pessoa.intContactID
                                   where emClassificacao.intQuestaoID == q.intQuestaoID
                                       && emClassificacao.intEmployeeID != pp.FiltroIntEmployeeID
                                   select new Professor
                                   {
                                       ID = pessoa.intContactID,
                                       Nome = pessoa.txtName,
                                       DataAcao = emClassificacao.dteDateTime
                                   }).FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What is favorita1? Is it a local variable?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! as incredible as it may seem, the problem was the visual studio 2015 just uninstalled and installed Visual Studio 2013, the project started to work again.